# Does IOS Archiving encrypt the objects

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

After attempting to upload my app to the App store I ran into Export compliance questions that I am not sure what I should answer to.

Does IOS Archiving encrypt the objects or does it "count" with regard to Itunes Connect Export Compliance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After attempting to upload my app to the App store I ran into Export compliance questions that I am not sure what I should answer to.

The questions only relate to code that is part of your application. It doesn't apply to anything that may be used as part of the application submission process.

> Does IOS Archiving encrypt the objects or does it "count" with regard to Itunes Connect Export Compliance.

No. It's just creating a ZIP archive of your compiled application -- there is no additional encryption being applied at this stage.

Comment: Thank you, by any chance would you happen to know about Firebase? I use it for analytics and Admob. Is it exempt from U.S. Export Administration Regulations?